# how to hide html5 player for ipad on done button click

Tags: html, ipad, video

I am playing vide in ipad it is working fine but i want that when user enter done button player should close any idea how to do this. i am using following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset=”utf-8″>
<meta name=”apple-mobile-web-app-capable” content=”yes” />
<title>My Video</title>
<link rel=”apple-touch-icon” href=”icon.png” />
<style>
body {margin:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<video width=”1024″ height=”750″ controls=”true”>
<source src=”videos/test.m4v” />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find FULL CODE here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset=”utf-8″>
<meta name=”apple-mobile-web-app-capable” content=”yes” />
<title>My Video</title>
<link rel=”apple-touch-icon” href=”icon.png” />
<script>
  function onClickDone(){
  document.getElementById('myvideotag').pause();
  document.getElementById('myvideotag').style.display = "none";
}
</script>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="onClickDone()">Done</button>
<video id="myvideotag" width=”1024″ height=”750″ controls=”true”>
<source src=”videos/test.m4v” />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hot to load this video bydefualt when video is loaded on full screen

Comment: /*===add this script on load ===*/

    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

Comment: replace "elem" with "document.getElementById('myvideotag')"

Comment: same problem not working here is code if (document.getElementById('myVideo').requestFullscreen) { document.getElementById('myVideo').requestFullscreen(); } else if (document.getElementById('myVideo').mozRequestFullScreen) { document.getElementById('myVideo').mozRequestFullScreen(); } else if (document.getElementById('myVideo').webkitRequestFullscreen) { document.getElementById('myVideo').webkitRequestFullscreen(); }

Comment: ooppsss Same problem here .requestFullscreen i need to post question .. lolz